# How can I extract the MCC and MNC from a PLMN?

Tags: gsm, at-command

I am running the AT command [AT+KCELL](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/skin/frontend/default/cooking/pdf/AT_Commands.pdf) to get cell information and it returns, amongst other things, a `PLMN` ([Public Land and Mobile Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_land_mobile_network)) - the description of this from the documentation is:

> PLMN identifiers (3 bytes), made of MCC (Mobile Country Code), and MNC
>   (Mobile Network Code).

OK, that matches what Wikipedia says - in there is the MCC and MNC.  Now what I don't understand is how do I extract the aforementioned MCC and MNC values?

Here is an example.  I get back:

```
32f210
```

and I am told (though I am sceptical) that that should result in:

```
MNC: 1
MCC: 232
```

but I can't for the life of me work out how to get that result from the PLMN so how do I parse this?

Comment: if you are on unix , you can try the cut command

Comment: I'm on a windows machine but I will read up on the cut command thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I have found this out and figured I would add an answer here in case there is some other unlucky soul who has to do this - the PDF called [GSM Technical Specification](https://cardboss.cometway.com/gsm11-11.pdf) (section 10.2.4) contains the answer, the relevant bit is:

> PLMN Contents: Mobile Country Code (MCC) followed by the Mobile Network Code (MNC). Coding: according to TS GSM 04.08 [14].
>
> - If storage
>     for fewer than the maximum possible number n is required, the excess
>     bytes shall be set to 'FF'. For instance, using 246 for the MCC and 81
>     for the MNC and if this is the first and only PLMN, the contents reads
>     as follows: Bytes 1-3: '42' 'F6' '18' Bytes 4-6: 'FF' 'FF' 'FF' etc.

So I was wrong to be sceptical!

I need to read from the left swapping the digits around so the first two bytes would be the MCC so that would be `232f` and the MNC would be `01` then I just discard the f and I have 232 and 1!  Glad that one is sorted.

For example, in c# you can do it like this:

```
string plmn = "whatever the plmn is";

string mcc = new string(plmn.Substring(0, 2).Reverse().ToArray())
    + new string(plmn.Substring(2, 2).Reverse().ToArray())
    .Replace('f', ' ')
    .Trim();

string mnc = new string(plmn.Substring(4, 2).Reverse().ToArray())
    .Replace('f', ' ')
    .Trim();
```

Comment: In fact MCC takes 3 nibbles, and MNC takes 3 nibbles (US operators have 3-digit MNC). And it's not a good idea to save MCC/MNC as numbers, as leading zeroes matter. So first we have to swap nibbles of PLMN, `32f210 => 232f01`, then we assign `MCC=232` and `MNC=01` (`f` is ignored). But if we would have operator having 3-digit MNC, then we would have the following: `PLMN=130203 => 312030 => MCC=312, MNC=030`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a java answer with bitwise operations:

```
public static String mcc(byte[] plmnId) {
  if (plmnId == null || plmnId.length != 3)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Wrong plmnid %s", Arrays.toString(plmnId)));

  int a1 = plmnId[0] & 0x0F;
  int a2 = (plmnId[0] & 0xF0) >> 4;
  int a3 = plmnId[1] & 0x0F;

  return "" + a1 + a2 + a3;
}

public static String mnc(byte[] plmnId) {
  if (plmnId == null || plmnId.length != 3)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Wrong plmnid %s", Arrays.toString(plmnId)));

  int a1 = plmnId[2] & 0x0F;
  int a2 = (plmnId[2] & 0xF0) >> 4;
  int a3 = (plmnId[1] & 0xF0) >> 4;

  if (a3 == 15)
    return "" + a1 + a2;
  else
    return "" + a1 + a2 + a3;
}
```